# How to draw a circle in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using this method to draw a circle in my app:

```
public void drawCircle(){       
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(52, 73, 94));
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);      
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 200, 60, paint);     
}
```

The problem is that the circle appears kind of oval and with pixellated edges.
I used the `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` but it didn't work.
How to draw a circle with smooth edges?

EDIT
I using a framework for games. from this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430246774](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430246774)

Comment: If the circle turns out oval, maybe your canvas is scaled or stretched somewhere? The coe you have posted -should- work.

Comment: Post your full code for this

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

     canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

}
```

For a better reference on drawing custom views check out the official Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm not doing this in a activity. I cannot override the onDraw.

Comment: @Roland Means you haven't created custom view for it?

Comment: I using a framework for games. from this book: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430246774

Comment: @Roland You can easily make one custom view and implement onDraw override method and draw circle.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(new MyView(this));
     }

     public class MyView extends View {
         public MyView(Context context) {
              super(context);
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }
     }
```

Comment: I'm not doing this in a activity. I cannot override the onDraw.